# Redirect to proxy using Webextensions API

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

How does one take an HTTP request and redirect it to proxy (on an ad-hoc basis, assuming browser is on no-proxy)?

For example: I want to access http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions.

In terms of the API, this request would look like this:

```
Method: Get
Url: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions

Headers
Host: www.stackoverflow.com
More-Headers: More-Values
```

If I have to send the same request to proxy, I need to add a proxy authorization header. I also need to change the URL to http://www.myproxy.com. How do I specify the URL of the website that I want to visit?

In terms of actual coding:

In onBeforeRequest callBack- I change the URL by returning {redirectUrl: https://www.myproxy.com}

In onBeforeSendHeaders callBack- I add the proxy auth header. I leave the Host header as is.

Where and how do I mention the URL of the target website I need content from?

Answer (score 1):

The webRequest API won't let you do what you're asking, you need the browser to handle the proxying.  The proxy API is meant to provide a way to do this, it is implemented in [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/proxy) and is currently (August 2016) being implemented in Firefox (tracking bug is https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1283639).